# Sync RGB strip lights with MIDI clock pulse input

Tags: pi-3, python, midi

I would like to create a lightshow of sorts, for my Keyboard, that can output a midi clock. I have a strip of WS2801 and I am looking for a way to sync colour changes/fades/flashes etc to the beat of music I'm playing. However, I am unable to find a python MIDI library that can read incoming midi clock in real time. Can anyone suggest a library, or better way of doing this, I am able to write the code myself, I just need pointing in the right direction.
Many Thanks

Comment: I can't see the problem with the Raspberry Pi. Where is it?

Comment: From my perspective there is no problem with the Pi, I just can't find a library that will let me do this.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far, and what issues did you run into? A quick search for "python midi" yields about a dozen distinct possibilities -- something called "mido" looks particularly promising.

Comment: I have installed mido, but I cant find anh documentation,